# Drawing all DrawableGameComponents in a single batch

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, draw, drawablegamecomponent

This is an XNA question...

I have a large number of objects that are DrawableGameComponents in my game and they all share the same SpriteBatch. However, I have to call SpriteBatch.Begin() and .End() everytime to draw each component. I want to draw everything in a single batch for better performance but I don't know where .Begin() and .End() can go since the .Draw() is being automatically called (as they are DrawableGameComponents)

Does anyone know what I can do to make them all be drawn between a single .Begin() and .End() call whilst keeping them as DrawableGameComponents?

Edit:

Alright from this website http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/XNA-Game-Development-(Decentralize).aspx I figured that it's called at the main game loop's base.Draw() call... so I can just wrap that with the Begin and End methods

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
    if (Cell.Cell.CellSpriteBatch != null) {
        Cell.Cell.CellSpriteBatch.Begin(
            SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, 
            SamplerState.AnisotropicClamp, null, null, null,
            gamePlay.Camera.GetTransformation()
        );
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime);

    if (Cell.Cell.CellSpriteBatch != null) {
        Cell.Cell.CellSpriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

and it works now but doing it this way seems to mean that everything else that I want drawn in a different SpriteBatch will always be drawn below this (as they are drawn first) because the .End() of this SpriteBatch is always going to be called last.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: do you really mean to be using anisotropic filtering? It's generally useless for sprite graphics.

Comment: Hi... I was wondering why you suddenly mentioned that, then I realized it was because the SamplerState was set to AnsiotropicClamp. That part is actually done by my teammate programming the Camera and I just checked with him - he says he doesn't know what it's for and I guess it has no reason to be there. I just changed it to the default LinearClamp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, unless you already know that you are batch limited its probably not worth doing this. If every single .Draw call is pulling from the same texture then you might see some speed up. If they are different textures then switching to a single Begin/End will have no difference. SpriteBatch will break up your draw calls anyway.

As you found doing this makes your code pretty confusing too - you have to keep track between components.

The only solution to your current problem is to make the SpriteBatch Immediate so that it draws as you call the draw calls instead of drawing at the End call. However this will kill your perf as no batching is done at all.

Personally I would stick to a Begin/End per component until you hit a perf problem. Assuming you don't have 5000 components that is in which case you probably need to architect things a little differently.

Comment: Yeah I guess the real solution is to architect things differently. The game I'm making has a big bunch of cells all over the place so at times it actually does reach 5000 components. I've structured the code to make sure certain things that need to be drawn on top are called last now so it's all working fine just that the code is really confusing... but since I'm running out of time, I'm just going to go with this. I agree though, that the best way is to fundamentally restructure my code, probably without using GameComponents.

Comment: Maybe one GameComponent for all cells and each cell represented by a class you create for it that has a Draw method.  There is some overhead with a GameComponent.  Are you really displaying 5000 sprites on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Remember that just because something is a GameComponent doesn't mean you have to add it to Game.GameComponents to be managed.
If you are using GameComponent as a base class for Sprite then that's just fine but add a SpriteManager to the components collection that has its own Components collection that you can manage better yourself. Then use that to handle when Being/End calls.
Use the Game.GameComponents collection for 'bigger groups' of things.